# Consume WCF websockets service by MonoDroid application

Tags: wcf, websocket, xamarin.android

I try to consume WCF service with Mono For Android application. Service has one endpoint with binding to SOAP over websockets. And websockets is a problem: there are no implementation of websockets in MonoDroid.

I add WebReference to project empty proxy class has generated. I try to rework proxy class successefully generated for Windows 8 but there are no DuplexClientBase implementation. I create custom implementation that just make request via WebSocket4Net.MonoDroid websockets implementation.

I can communicate with plaint text messages but I really need somthing that generates and parse SOAP messages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some other protocol. E.g. protocol buffers via HTTP or custom XML.

Comment: Yes SOAP over HTTP will be work fine, MonoDroid support it. But websockets is requirement from server side.